# Expected space error issue with gadicc/meteor-reactive-window Meteor Package

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, meteor-packages

Using [gadicc/meteor-reactive-window Meteor Package](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-reactive-window) to display diffrent template depending upon the screen size.
This is pictureDisplatSection.html File

```
            <template name="pictureDisplaySection">
                <div class="display">

                {{#if rwindow.screen('lte','small') }}
                    {{> small}}         
                {{else}}        
                    {{> large}}         
                {{/if}}

                Current jQuery(window).width() is {{rwindow.$width}}
                </div>

            </template>

            <template name="small">
                I am Small
            </template>
            <template name="large">
                I am Large
            </template>
```

This code has started working intially but out of the blue it has started giving this error

While building the application:
client\template\pictureDisplaySection.html: 4 : Expected space
  ...    {{#if rwindow.screen('lte','small') }}
...
^

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

I have tried to find more information but no luck till now. Really appreciate some help.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a syntax error. Inside the `if` block, the function receives arguments with a space separated instead of parenthesis `(..,..,)`。

```
{{#if rwindow.screen 'lte' 'small'}}
  {{> small}}         
{{else}}        
  {{> large}}         
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Max , just a silly mistake can become so large. One more issue Max , when I use {{ #if rwindow.screen 'lte'  500}} , nothing gets displayed.just background. Meteor is not showing any error , I have also tried {{ #if rwindow.screen 'lte'  '500'}} but same result , I believe 500 is the width of screen , am I right

Comment: Yes, I think so. Maybe `rwindow.screen` doesn't accept a number as its second argument but only `xsmall`, `small`, `medium` and  `large`.

Comment: Thanks @Max for responding .Keep up your kind work Cheers :)